# Cannot access 'TAG': it is private in 'FragmentActivity'

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm on getting an error at word `TAG`:

> 'Cannot access 'TAG': it is private in 'FragmentActivity''

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        MainBtn.setOnClickListener {

            val nextIntent = Intent(this, SubActivity1::class.java)
            startActivity(nextIntent)
            finish()
        }

        val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        val myRef = database.getReference("message")

        myRef.setValue("Hello, World!")
        myRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val value =
                    dataSnapshot.getValue(String::class.java)
                Log.d(FragmentActivity.TAG, "Value is: $value")
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w(FragmentActivity.TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException())
            }
        })
    }
}
```

How I can fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Field `TAG` from class `FragmentActivity` is private. So, you can't access it outside of `FragmentActivity` class. That class is part of the Android SDK, so, you can just make that field `public`. Instead, you must create and use your own tag.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        const val TAG = "MainActivity"
    }

    ....
    // Use just TAG
    Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After `log.w` press `""` and the tag will come automatically. You won't need to create `const TAG`.

```
log.w( " )
```